# Forward and backward navigation buttons for Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am porting an iPhone app to Android, and I can't find the Android equivalent of the UINavigationItem.  These are buttons with a triangular side indicating movement between different screens.  For an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, this is from the BeyondPod app:
http://mobiputing.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/beyondpod.jpg

The buttons labeled "Categories" and Podcasts" are what I'd like to duplicate.

Comment: You should not try to make an exact copy of what you made for iPhone on the android or any other platform. Each one has its own styles and conventions in which the end users are used to. What jeff has given in the answer is the android style of navigation.

Comment: Fair enough. The back button was already working, so I just removed the interface button entirely.  Just wondering though... would you say that the BeyondPod example I linked was simply doing it wrong? What do you think they did, created their own buttons? On their interface, the back button and the left arrow button serve the same function, but using the left and right buttons is kind of intuitive there because it lets you flip back and forth to multiple screens.

Answer (score 1):

Android has a hardware back button.  Forward is typically accomplished by some widget, such as a button or link, somewhere in the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the screenshot you posted again and noticed that your left and right buttons are to switch between categories and not to go to an earlier screen.(Im not sure if im right)

If that's the case using the left and right buttons are okay as they are to switch between categories and not the previous screen. But keeping a left button just to go to the previous screen isn't really necessary. Here we need to think in terms of an android user. They are hardwired to press the hardware back button to go to a previous screen. There are many examples of apps that have a bit of changes in their android and iPhone version. Eg Evernote.
It uses tabs on the iPhone but in android they sort of created a dashboard in combination with an action bar.

So main thing to consider when porting an iphone app is to make enough changes so that an android user will feel like it has a navigation they are used to. Most apps that look exactly the same as iphone apps are created with these cross mobile development tools(titanium, sencha touch).